# How is user mapping achieved during migration from MKS to SVN using svn-importer?

Tags: svn, migration, mks, mks-integrity

I have got a task to migrate MKS to SVN for some client. I am familiar with SVN and I used it for 4 years.

There is only one converter that I could find out in internet. 
Its Free Subversion Data Migration Tool: **Importer for SVN** from **Polarion Software** 

The documentation of the software is very good with clear explanation on mapping of concepts like Revisions, Branches, etc.

But the **documentation doesn't mention anything about users mapping**. It doesn't say how should it be done or managed. I could not find much info after searching through the internet.

**Can anyone please let me know how the users are mapped from MKS to SVN and how should we achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/svn_importer_features.php#MKS

> The transformation preserves revisions, authors, commit messages and dates of commits

If you check the source for `org.polarion.svnimporter.mksprovider.internal.MksTransform`

```
    /**
     * create a new SVN revision based on MksCommit
     * @param commit MksCommit object used to construct SVN revision
     */
private void createSvnRevision(MksCommit commit) {
    svnModel.createNewRevision(commit.getAuthor(), commit.getDate(), commit.getMessage());
    svnModel.getCurRevision().getProperties().set("MKSRevisionNumbers", commit.joinRevisionNumbers());
}
```